# ¿Cómo puedo mandar a imprimir a impresoras locales desde sistema web?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, google-api

Tengo un sistema web, el cual es html y javascript, el cual realiza todas sus operaciones por ajax conectándose a un servicio web c#.

Hasta ahí todo perfecto, lo que quería implementar es que el usuario pueda seleccionar todos sus documentos de una grilla y mandarlos a imprimir directamente a la impresora por defecto del cliente, y si no tuviera una impresora por defecto, que se muestre la lista de impresoras locales y de red del cliente, la detección de sus impresoras deben de ser por javascript.

Lo que llegué a hacer fue implementar el servicio de `Google cloud print`, el cual me permite registrar cualquier impresora y usarla desde mi sistema web[image: Listado de impresoras asociadas a google cloud print] y puedo imprimir sin ningún problema, pero eso me obliga a registrar manualmente las impresoras entrando a mi cuenta de gmail y asociar yo mismo la impresora [image: Asociación de impresora a google cloud], y esto es un problema debido a que el cliente debería poder ser capaz de registrarlo el mismo a través de mi sistema web.

El sistema web esta publicado en un host con dominio y se accede a traves de internet, mas no por una red local

Espero haber sido especifico y me puedan ayudar.

Dato: He visto preguntas de este tipo que dices que el cliente no podria mostrar las impresoras por que sera una falla de seguridad.

Comment: Debes poner las pruebas que hayas hecho, de todas formas, que lenguaje de los 2 que nombras es el que manda a imprimir y el que te debe pedir la impresora si no hay predeterminada?

Comment: te invito a [recorrer el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) , y [leer como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No soy experto en la materia, pero lo que pides no me suena posible. Y si fuera posible, me parece que sería un grave problema de seguridad.

Comment: Locales para el usuario, para el servidor o para ambos?

Comment: Es importante aclarar lo que pregunta @PabloLozano. Hace falta que especifiques un poco mas el esquema de tu sistema (donde está el servidor, acceden los clientes a la aplicación web desde una red local o por internet, las impresoras estarían en el lado cliente o en el servidor,etc...)